# The Concise Conditional "?"

Tags: php, conditional-statements

The first php script below does show "exactly seven", but the other one does not. Any idea why?

--- This one work ---

```
<?
$num = 7;
echo ($num == 7) ? "exactly seven" : "not seven";
?>
```

--- This one does not ---

```
<?
$num = 7;
echo ($num == 7) ? "exactly seven" : ($num > 7) ? "more than seven" : "less than seven";
?>
```

Comment: What *does* the second one output?

Comment: @admdrew I'm not sure you're following the point of this question

Comment: The output is "more than seven".

Comment: [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) `It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:`

Comment: @admdrew Not really, PHP's implementation of the ternary operator is left to right (unlike the standard right to left associative).

Comment: @thescientist whoops, yeah I misread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called precedence of operators. Add some parenthesis to ensure things happen in the right order, e.g.

```
$num = 7;
echo ($num == 7) ? "exactly seven" : (($num > 7) ? "more than seven" : "less than seven");
```

Comment: To clarify, in PHP the ? operator is *left* associative. Not right, like C and most other languages. This is *very* counter-intuitive. Just don't nest 'em.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! :) Thumbs Up

Answer (score 4):

The result of the first part of the expression, `($num == 7) ? "exactly seven" : ($num > 7)` is used as input for the other one.

So the expression can be read as `echo "exactly seven" ? "more than seven" : "less than seven";`.

Since `"exactly seven"` evaluates to boolean true, the echoed value is "more than seven".

Answer (score 0):

As it's been said, it's in the precedence of operators. The behavior of your line of code

```
echo ($num == 7) ? "exactly seven" : ($num > 7) ? "more than seven" : "less than seven";
```

is called the `Non-obvious ternary behavior`. The evaluation happens from left to right so

```
1. echo (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) ? (expr4) : (expr5)
2. evaluates the first ternary operator `?` to 
   echo (expr2) ? (expr4) : (expr5) 
   //because expr1 was TRUE ($num == 7)
3. and since the expr2 is "exactly seven" it finally evaluates to 
   echo (expr4).
```